# how to use select into creating a macro array with numeric value descending

Tags: sas

I am use select into creating a macro array

```
proc sql;

select numValue into:num_value separated by ' ' from tableA;

quit;



%put %scan(num_value,1);
```

however,the value in macro num_value  did not arrange their numeric values from its original order（from small to large）.

so how could I arrage their values descending or ascending depending on their index,or the macro array has a same order as the original table is.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to order value in macro variable, you could do something like this:

```
proc sql;
   select height into:height from sashelp.class order by height;
quit;

%put &height;
```

Comment: may be you have to add separated by '  '.                                                         proc sql;
   select height into :height SEPARATED by '  ' from sashelp.class order by height;
quit;

%put &height;

Answer (score 1):

Code: Values ordered in descending order below, the default order is ascending if you don't specify.

```
proc sql;
   select height into:height separated by ' ' from sashelp.class order by height desc;
quit;

%put &height;
```

Log:

```
72 69 67 66.5 66.5 65.3 64.8 64.3 63.5 62.8 62.5 62.5 59.8 59 57.5 57.3 56.5 56.3 51.3
```

Output:

[image: SQL output]